# p-values and predicted standard errors using cplm

Tags: anova, p-value, prediction

I am using the cpglmm-function from the "cplm" package to model the effect of treatment, time and host age on logged parasite counts.

This type of data has a big peak at zero, but follows a continuous poisson-distribution, so ideal to use with cplm's compound poisson tweedie distribution.

The model runs fine and I am using dredge() to test which main effects should be maintained in the minimal model. However, I am struggling to obtain p-values for the main effects of the minimal models. Further, I can use predict() to obtain predictions based on the model and sample data, but there is no option for computing standard errors (I think).

Here's the minimal model:
m2.3 <- cpglmm(logparasite ~ trt*week + Age + (1|ID), data = data2)

for the p-values, I've so far dropped individual terms from the minimal model and then compared those using anova() with log-likelihood ration test.

for getting standard errors on my predictions I haven't found a good solution yet.

any help with those issues would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!!